# problems installing pyqt in macOs

Tags: macos, installation, pyqt

HI,

I´m trying to install pyqt in macos.
I read on Internet that i need: sip + pyqt + qt (obviously)
I had no problem installing qt & sip.
When I try to install pyqt I can see the following error at the terminal:

```
    python configure.py
    Error: A Qt installation could not be found. Use the -q argument or the QTDIR environment variable to explicitly specify the correct directory.
```

Anybody knows what I should write at the terminal?

Thanks,

NAcho

Answer (score 1):

python configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-4.x

x being whatever qmake version you have, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install PyQt for Qt 3 or PyQt4 for Qt 4?

The error message looks like the one from PyQt for Qt 3, in which case the argument to the -q option is the directory containing the bin, lib and include directories where the Qt executables, libraries and header files are installed.